# kafka integration with spark streaming java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost:2181 using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

```
 val reciver = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("spark-topic" -> 5))
```

j'ai testé le code ci dessus . il  m'affiche un  exception  de type : java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost:2181

Comment: As tu démarré Zookeeper? C'est lui qui tourne au port 2181.

Comment: oui  bien sur  j'ai  démarrer  Zookeeper